# Spring JPA and MySQL stores incorrect LocalDateTime value

Tags: mysql, spring, database, jpa, localdatetime

I'm using Spring Data JPA to store a datetime value in a MySQL table column. But it's acting really weird. When I create the entity that should be stored, where I have LocalDateTime field for create date and time, the field is set through LocalDateTime.now(). When I debug the code and see the code in action, the LocalDateTime field gets instantiated with the right date and time. But for some reason when the entity gets stored in the MySQL database, the time gets set to two hours in the past. If the time is 4 pm it gets set to 2pm in the database table. But then as I read the value in the database again with my jpa repository it gets pushed 2 hours ahead again, despite the fact that it got stored with a tho hour offset. So it's kinda like two wrongs make a right... I guess? How can this be? This seems like crazy and just... illogical. It's local development if that matters.

Comment: Try to retrieve that 'wrong' value (In Spring). If the retrieved value is the actual date and time, then it's your database doing the time zone convertions.

Comment: Using newer JDBC driver (≥8.0.22) should fix the problem. See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93444 for the details.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this problem earlier because of DB so initially, I tried reducing time and minutes, however, it wasn't working. So I reload the app and DB then it was working fine.
U can try it may be work for u

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is related to the DB it is not the problem related to your code.

I have a different approach which is work in my system

```
 Instant instant = Instant.now();
 Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(instant);
```

use this timestamp to set date and time and also you have to change the entity class property

```
private Timestamp publishedAt;
```

I hope It will work!!

Answer (score 0):

Try it with these annotations

```
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "published_at")
    private Date publishedAt;
```